# Prevent Perl eval stopping when it meets a blank line in the passed input?

Tags: perl, eval

For reason I'm not going to go into, I have a Perl script that reads a text file and then executes it on order to build up a config.

When ever there is a blank line in the text file being evaled, everything after the blank line does not happen, so I'm assuming Perl is treating an empty line as some kind of indication that it should stop evaling or something.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour?

The Code:

```
open my $CONFIGFILE, '<', $config_file || return 0;
my $config_code = do{local $/ = q{}; <$CONFIGFILE>};
close $CONFIGFILE;
my $config;
unless(eval $config_code){
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us some code. Otherwise, this question cannot be answered (or, the answer is "no".)

Comment: You're assuming wrong, so your question is invalid. Give us some information that might let us figure out what's *actually* going on, please.

Comment: Given the explained behavior, it should be VERY easy to build a simple example script that does the same thing and either fails identically or not. if it does, post it here to improve the question. If it doesn't, your theory is wrong and something else is broken in your code.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing something like `while ($_=eval(<>)) ...`, in which case any non-true value (such as an empty line, or zero) will break the loop. You might consider checking if [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) can work for you instead, e.g. `do "filename.txt"`.

Comment: I've added in the lines of code as requested

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're reading every line in, manipulating it and then building a huge string to eval (which is then breaking).

You have a few choices:

1) read in the configuration file, skipping any blank lines as you read.  IE, something like:

```
while(<>) {
   next if (/^\s*$/);
   # do $string collection here
}
eval($string);
```

2) capture the eval results one at a time:

```
while(<>) {
    $string = super_secret_read_and_modify($_);
    eval($string);
}
```

With #1 and #2 you can discard things that are breaking your code.  I suspect you're running into problems because the data you're evaluating isn't valid.  So you either need to fix your construction or break the evals into smaller pieces so that the eval of a single piece doesn't stop the rest from working.